# c++ deleting vector class member memory in destructor

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I have a class containing a vector member variable.
I know that vectors stored on the stack will be
cleaned up (i.e. memory free'd) when they go out of
scope, but I'm not sure if the destruction of a
class object - which contains a vector member variable -
is considered going out of scope.

If it isn't, what's the appropriate way to destruct
the vector?

EG:

```
class fred {
    char *stuff;
    vector<int> v;

    fred() : stuff(), v() {}
    ~fred() {
         if (stuff) free(stuff);
         // now how do I clear up the vector v?  Will it be done automatically?
    }
 }
```

Comment: Seeing as how it's tagged C++, you probably want `new/delete` over `malloc/free`.

Comment: vector is fine. But `stuff` is not safe because of the copy constructor and assignment operator (because the compiler will generate them automatically). See the rule of three (or five in C++11).

Comment: In the new world, C++11-land, you no longer call `delete` yourself. You use unique_ptrs(usually) or shared_ptrs(rarely) to call it for you.

Answer (score 8):

The vector is cleaned up for you already! When a class gets destructed all of it's members destructors are also called. In this case `v`'s destructor is called, which cleans up whatever it allocated.

Non-static members' dtors are called when you reach the closing `}` of the destructor in the reverse order they were declared in. Then your base class destructor is called, if present.

Comment: That's great, but I thought that if I was writing my own destructor for the class (not relying on the default one), then that automatic cleanup wouldn't occur. You are saying the vectors destructor will be called even though I have an explicit destructor??

Comment: Yes. For all non-static, non-pointer member objects, the dtor is called automatically once you reach the '}' of the dtor body in the order in which these members were defined in the class definition (and then the base class dtors are called which in turn delete base members, if any and so on ...).

Comment: @dirkgently Correction: the dtors of members are called in the _reverse_ order in which they were _declared_ in the class _declaration_

Comment: @Dave: Yep, I was trying to cram as much as I could and in the process mixed it up a bit :/

Answer (score 0):

The destructor for the vector will be called when you destroy an instance of fred.

Comment: `v` is not necessarily on the stack! It depends whether this instance of `fred` was allocated on the stack or not

Comment: Oh right! Didn't consider that case :(
Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: He may not have to *destroy* the `fred` instance if it has automatic storage duration i.e. stack allocated instance.

Comment: When I said "you destroy", I meant "when it is destroyed".

Answer (score 0):

I think you need not call DTOR for the vector. The DTOR will be called as soon as the object goes out of scope, meaning the DTOR of fred is Called.

Answer (score 0):

There is always ONLY ONE way to destroy an object, and that is by its destructor (in contrast, you can construct objects in several ways). STL containers were designed specifically to avoid such micromanagement of memory within data structures. If you are having to explicitly allocate or free memory in an STL container, you're doing it wrong.